# How to save a tensor in checkpoint in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use tf.train.Saver() to make checkpoint of a tensor, here is my code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    var = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="biases")
    temp = tf.add(var, 0.1)
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    saver = tf.train.Saver({'w':temp})

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        print(sess.run(temp))
```

but got an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_counter.py", line 61, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver({'w':temp})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1043, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1073, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 649, in build
    saveables = self._ValidateAndSliceInputs(names_to_saveables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 578, in _ValidateAndSliceInputs
     variable)
   TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("TransformFeatureToIndex:0", shape=(100,), dtype=string)
```

One way I think about is storing the Tensor in client by sess.run(temp) and save, but is there a more significant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`temp` is not a `tf.Variable`, but an operation. It "has" no value or state, it is just a node in the graph. If you want to save the result of adding to `var` explicitely, you can assign `temp` to another variable by `tf.assign` and save this other variable.  The easier way would probably be to save `var` (or the whole session), and after restoring just evaluate `temp` again.

Comment: Thanks, tf.assign works! For my real situation, I used self-defined ops which is much complicated than tf.add, so evaluating `temp` is expensive, the tf.assign is mush suitable for my case.